# Sveltekit fails to load certain page data without Vite hot update

Tags: typescript, firebase, svelte, sveltekit

I am new to Sveltekit and Typescript (which I am using), and have encountered a strange issue which only occurs on the most recent page I'm working on for a project of mine. I'm using the latest version of Sveltekit alongside Firebase for authentication, database, and storage.

The site serves as a repository to put in data about their characters, show that information to other people by linking to their page. Users can also request social media style relationships between their characters.

At a route `/[username]/requests` I am making an inbox-outbox interface which shows the user any outstanding relationship requests they may have and allows them to accept/decline or cancel requests. In this directory there is `+layout.ts` and `+page.svelte`.

`+layout.ts` queries the "requests" collection of the database for requests which involve the user's characters, and exports to `+page.svelte` a "Mail" object which contains the DocumentData of each character involved in the exchange for use on the page. It also uses and exports a bit of data inherited from `/[username]/+layout.server.ts`, specifically the user's username and list of characters. This pattern is replicated on other pages, such as for character viewing and creation: `/[username]/+layout.server.ts` provides user data which child pages use to query the database in some fashion.

This requests page is uniquely troubling though, because it only seems to populate the `+page.svelte` with the data retrieved by `+layout.ts` after a hot update from Vite. I can refresh the page outright and nothing will happen, but once I update the DOM by just making a div or something in VSC, it displays the objects generated using the page data as expected: [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpR6U.png). Furthermore, it's only some of the data that has this holdup: the parent data from `+layout.server.ts` can be combined with Svelte HTML stuff just fine, but anything from `+layout.ts` refuses to populate.

No other pages I've made do this, and even odder, the data is actually correctly output by a console.log (received as an "incomingMail" array filled with Mail objects and the same for outgoingMail), so it seems that the data is correctly fetched and exported (all code 200 OKs in the network tab). I have been tearing my hair out over this. Here are some samples of the code, truncated to get to the point:

```js
// /[username]/+layout.server.ts


export const load = (async ({ params }) => {

    const q = query(
        ccollection(db, "users"),
        where("username", "==", params.username),
        limit(1)
      );
    
    const snapshot = await getDocs(q);
    const exists = snapshot.docs[0]?.exists();
    const data = snapshot.docs[0]?.data();

    if (!exists) {
        throw error(404, "This user does not exist!");
    }

    return {
        username: data.username,
        characterList: data.characterList,
    };
}) satisfies LayoutServerLoad;
```

```js
// /[username]/requests/+layout.ts

export const load = (async ({ parent }) => {

    const data = await parent()

    const collectionRef = collection(db, "requests");

    const toQ = query( // incoming requests to this user's characters
        collectionRef,
        where("to", "in", data.characterList),
    );

    interface Mail { 
        to: DocumentData | undefined,
        from: DocumentData | undefined,
        type: string,
    }
    
    let incomingMail: Mail[] = [];
    (await getDocs(toQ)).forEach( async (mail) => { 

        if (mail.exists()) {

            const mailContent = mail.data()

            const to = (await getDoc(doc(db, "characters", mailContent.to))).data()
            const from = (await getDoc(doc(db, "characters", mailContent.from))).data()
            const type = mailContent.type // just a string

            incomingMail.push({ to : to, from : from, type : type })
        }
    });

    return {
        username : data.username,
        incomingMail : incomingMail,
    };
}) satisfies LayoutLoad;
```

And then in `+page.svelte`, imagine this basically, but with fancy styling and whatnot:

```html
// /[username]/requests/page.svelte

{#each data.incomingMail as mail}

<div>TO: {mail.to?.name.first}</div>
<div>FROM: {mail.from?.name.first}</div>

//...

{/each}
```

I have tried using stores, fetching data directly in layout.ts instead of its parent, setting data.incomingMail to a reactive variable, but none of these solutions did anything. I imagine this has to do with hydration somehow.

Comment: Your first step should be to isolate the problem and create a *minimal*, standalone example. Remove everything that can possibly be removed. This alone might help you solve the problem and would give anyone here something to work with directly. If you can make a simple example that can be directly opened on [sveltelab.dev](https://sveltelab.dev/) or [stackblitz.com](https://stackblitz.com/edit/svelte-kit) that would be ideal (but all code has to be in the question as well).

Comment: Similar issue... This helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37576787